# Is there an Arduino motor shield library?

Tags: arduino-motor-shield

I have an old motor shield but can see the revision 3 is still being sold: https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-motor-shield-rev3

When I follow the link for "Getting Started section" [the page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/HomePage) lists a lot of shields but not the motor shield.  I must be missing something really obviously but I can't find a library for the motor board.

I'm trying to drive 2 DC motors.

Comment: Have you googled this, before asking here? I googled "Arduino motor shield rev3 library" and directly found [this library on github](https://github.com/gallingern/arduino-motor-shield-r3). Have you tried it or any other library?

Comment: Yes for the last 90 minutes: https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=arduino+motor+shield+library&addon=opensearch https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=arduino+motor+shield+library+-adafruit https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.arduino.cc%2Fen%2FGuide%2F+motor+shield&addon=opensearch https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+motor+shield+library+example Granted that for me: https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+motor+shield+library shows your link as the fifth result down for but then it's followed by Adafruit Motor Shield again... their SEO is *too* good.

Comment: Ok so using Ecosia is part of the "problem", along with Adafruit's SEO... but I just realised Ecosia is powered by bing.com  and the extreme irony is that this question is already indexed as result number 7 but the library you helpfully provided is not! https://www.bing.com/search?q=arduino+motor+shield+library  LOL

Comment: Often it is helpful to add the term github to your search, since almost every Arduino library is hosted there.

Comment: Thanks @chrisl something seriously weird is going on with all my filter bubbles because your result now **isn't** shown in my google search after being shown in it minutes before... * so confused *.  Adding github just shows the Adafruit barrage, at least on page 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Chrisl's comment](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/65977/is-there-an-arduino-motor-shield-library/65979#comment140786_65977): https://github.com/gallingern/arduino-motor-shield-r3

You don't really need a library though as the code is simple enough:

```
void setup() {

  //Setup Channel A
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT); //Initiates Motor Channel A pin
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT); //Initiates Brake Channel A pin

}

void loop(){

  //forward @ full speed
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH); //Establishes forward direction of Channel A
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);   //Disengage the Brake for Channel A
  analogWrite(3, 255);   //Spins the motor on Channel A at full speed

  delay(3000);

  digitalWrite(9, HIGH); //Engage the Brake for Channel A
}
```

[From here](https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Motor-Shield-Tutorial/).